# Help with proof of "If $\lim s_n$ is defined [as a real number, $+\infty$, or $-\infty$], then $\liminf s_n=\lim s_n=\limsup s_n$"

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to understand the proof to Theorem 10.7(i) in Ross's [Elementary Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1461462703). I've found other proofs for the theorem, but my issue is in understanding the specific details in Ross's proof, and these haven't helped. Additionally, I haven't gotten to subspaces yet. My questions are within brackets within the proof. Thanks!

Here are the definitions of lim sup and lim inf that I'm given:
$$\limsup s_n=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sup\{s_n:n\gt N\}$$
$$\liminf s_n=\lim_{N\to\infty}\inf\{s_n:n\gt N\}$$

Theorem 10.7

Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

(i) If $\lim s_n$ is defined [as a real number, $+\infty$, or $-\infty$], then $\liminf s_n=\lim s_n=\limsup s_n$.

Proof

We use the notation $u_{N}=\inf\{s_n:n\gt N\}$, $v_{N}=\sup\{s_n:n\gt N\}$, $u=\lim u_{N}=\liminf s_n$ and $v=\lim v_{N}=\limsup s_n$.

Suppose $\lim s_n=+\infty$. Let M be a positive real number. Then there is a positive integer N so that
$$n\gt N \text { implies} \,s_n\gt M. $$

Then $u_{N}=\inf\{s_n:n\gt N\} \ge M.$ **[Why is it $\ge M?$ Why isn't it just $\gt M?$]** It follows that $m\gt N$ implies $u_m \ge M.$ **[Where does m come from? Is it arbitrary? What is $u_m$? Is it just another item in the sequence $(u_{N})$?]** In other words, the sequence $(u_{N})$ satisfies the condition defining $\lim u_{N}=+\infty$, i.e., $\liminf s_n=+\infty.$ Likewise $\limsup s_n=+\infty.$

The case of $\lim s_n=-\infty$ is handled in a similar manner.

Now suppose $\lim s_n=s$ where s is a real number. Consider $\epsilon>0.$ There exists a positive integer $N$ such that $|s_n-s|<\epsilon$ for $n>N$. Thus $s_n < s + \epsilon$ **[How does this follow? I read it is from the triangle inequality, but I don't see how it follows.]** for $n>N$, so

$$v_{N}=\sup\{s_n:n\gt N\}\le s+\epsilon$$.

Also, $m>N$ implies $v_m \le s+\epsilon$ **[Why is it necessary to state this? It seems like it was just shown with $v_{N}$.]**, so $\limsup s_n = \lim v_m \le s+ \epsilon.$ Since $\limsup s_n \le s + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, no matter how small, we conclude $\limsup s_n \le \lim s_n$. A similar argument shows $\lim s_n \le \liminf s_n.$ Since $\liminf s_n \le \limsup s_n$, we infer all three numbers are equal:

$$\liminf s_n = \lim s_n = \limsup s_n.$$

Answer (score 0):

1. Because the infimum of a set of numbers greater than $M$ doesn't have to be greater than $M$. All you can say is that it is greater than *or equal to* $M$.
2. Before this, the sequence $(u_N)_{N\in\Bbb N}$ was defined and $u_m$ is a term of this sequence, with $m>N$.
3. It follows from$$s_n-s\leqslant|s_n-s|<\varepsilon\implies s_n<s+\varepsilon.$$
4. Yes, it was shown just for $v_N$, but the *same* argument proves that $m>N\implies v_n<s+\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thanks Jose! For 2, it seems like the definition of $\lim s_n=+\infty$ has been met by $u_{N}$. Why does it again need to be shown for $u_m$?

Comment: For 4, I understand how $v_m \le s+\epsilon$ follows in the proof. I just don't see why it's necessary, since it was just shown that $v_{N} \le s+\epsilon$. Why show it again, why can't you use $v_{N}$?

Comment: Asserting that “the definition of $\lim s_n=+\infty$ has been met by $u_N$” makes no sense. The number $N$ is just one natural number. Asserting that $\lim s_n=+\infty$ means that, for every $M>0$, you have $s_n>M$ for **every** $n$ large enough.

Comment: For 2, what I mean is that it seems like the definition for a limit of $+\infty$ has already been satisfied with $u_{N}$. Why do you need to show that $u_m$ satisfies it too?

Comment: I have already provided an answer to that question in my previous comment.